Why was Blind Lemech Carrying a Bow?
Rashi (Genesis 4:23) states that Lemech and Tuval Cain killed Cain: they mistook him for a wild animal.

"Lamech was blind and Tubal-Cain used to lead him. The latter saw Cain and thought him to be an animal. He therefore told his father to draw the bow ..."


שֶׁהָיָה לֶמֶךְ סוּמָא וְתוּבַל קַיִן מוֹשְׁכוֹ, וְרָאָה אֶת קַיִן וְנִדְמָה לוֹ כְּחַיָּה וְאָמַר לְאָבִיו לִמְשֹׁךְ בַּקֶּשֶׁת וַהֲרָגוֹ

Per Tosfot in Sanhedrin, however, pre-diluvian man could not hunt for meat.
Tosfot Sanhedrin 56b

היינו להמית ולאכול אבל מתה מאליה שריא
(the prohibition) was to kill and eat (meat) but if (the animal) died on its own (eating meat was) permissible

Rashi, too, concedes that meat was not permitted to pre-diluvian man (9:3).
Why was Lemech carrying a bow? Why did Lemech and Tuval Kayin attempt to kill an animal?

Self defense?
Some sort of chiluk between killing for meat which is assur v. killing for another human purpose? (This needs further explanation - why would killing an animal be permitted for its skin, FE, but not to eat?) (perhaps, this is how Tosfot learns the Tanchuma - Genesis 11 - that states that Lemech was a regular hunter -
וסומא היה יוצא לצוד/He would go out hunting (regularly) blind).

I'm leaning away from answer one. Why would the father of all weaponry urge a blind man to 'take the shot' if this was a matter of urgent self-defense?

The prophylactic eradication of a dangerous animal (before it became a problem) from a safe distance? "Why wait for the animal to menace us?" This scenario gives the blind Lemech a chance to participate in 'hunting.' Seems negligent to let a blind man 'hunt.'

Tosfot could disagree with the whole bow and arrow story - it never happened. But what does Rashi do?

These two individuals didn't care about any hunting/meat issurim? (perhaps, this is how Tosfot learns the Tanchuma - Genesis 11 - that states that Lemech was a regular hunter -
וסומא היה יוצא לצוד/He would go out hunting (regularly) blind.


I think a neat question emerges. Per Tosfot, what if they would have killed the animal in self defense. Could they then eat it?

I found some helpful sources - Aruch LaNer Sanhedrin 59 and footnote ...



A summary, translation, or paraphrase would greatly improve this answer. Otherwise it is effectively a "link-only" answer: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3439/2394
